# How to construct a $C^1$ variation of the unique, minimal geodesic to its first conjugate point

Tags: riemannian-geometry

This is a question that I encountered when reading Proposition 1.8 of the paper "Optimal transport and curvature" by Alessio Figalli and Cedric Villani, whose proof is only outlined and involves construction of a $C^1$ variation of the unique, minimal geodesic connecting 2 distinct points (to study the Riemannian distance function). *This proposition asserts that the squared Riemannian distance function from a fixed point to another is differentiable at the other point if there is a unique minimizing geodesic connection these two points*. So, basically we are looking into the differeitability of the squared distance function, for which each member (i.e., for each fixed $s$) of the variation $c(s,t)$ has to be a minimizing geodesic and the variation has to be "good enough" to allow passing differentiation with respect to $s$ under the integral with respect to $t$ (e.g., a sufficient condition for this is that $c(s,t)$ is $C^1$ in $s$).

A snapshot of this proportion and its proof outline is attached:
[image: Prop1.8 and outline of proof]

However, my question is a specific scenario of the original setting, and it is also motivated by my study on *first conjugate points with unique minimal geodesics* (in a related post here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403600/riemannian-geometry-differentiability-of-distance-function-at-first-conjugate)

**Description of question:** Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold with distance function $d$. Fix two distinct points $p, q \in M$, and consider the case where there is a **unique, minimizing geodesic** $\gamma$ connection $p$ and $q$, such that **$q$ is the first conjugate to $p$** along $\gamma$. Here "minimizing" means "length or distance minimizing", i.e., $d(\gamma(0),\gamma(t))=t$ for $t \in [0,d(p,q)]$. Such a setting exits on, e.g., a paraboloid; see, e.g., Figure 2 of the paper "Spectral Flow, Maslov Index And Bifurcation Of Semi-Riemannian Geodesics"  by Paolo Piccione, Alessandro Portaluri, And Daniel V. Tausk.

How to construct a $C^1$ variation $c(s,t)$ of $\gamma$ for $(s,t) \in (-a,a) \times [0,d(p,q)]$ for some $a>0$, such that the following hold:

1. $c(0,t)=\gamma(t)$ for all $t \in [0,d(p,q)]$, and $c(s,0)=p$ for all $s \in (-a,a)$, and
2. for each fixed $s \in (-a,a)$, $c(s,t)$ is a minimizing geodesic connecting $p=c(s,0)$ and $c(s,d(p,q))$, and
3. for each fixed $t \in [0,d(p,q)]$, $c(s,t)$ is **continuously differentiable in $s$** for $s \in (-a,a)$?

**Background research:** There is a post here under the title "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3726838/constructing-a-proper-variation-through-geodesics-at-cut-locus". But the discussion for it was diverted and the question in title was never discussed or answered. Also, I have looked through 3 textbooks (John M. Lee's "Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds", Takashi Sakai's "Riemannian Geometry", and Peter Petersen's "Riemannian Geometry") for a hint on how to construct such a variation but found one. All these textbooks provide variations $c(s,t)= \exp_{p}(t(\gamma'(0)+s \mathbf{w}))$, which do not satisfy item 2 given above.

The key difficulty I see to constructing a $C^1$ variation of $\gamma$ when $q$ is in the cut locus of $p$ is the non-uniqueness of geodesics connection $p$ and a point in any neighborhood of $q$ (except possibly $q$ itself), since Theorem 2.1.12 on page 133 of W.A. Klingenberg's book "Riemannian Geometry" states that, within any neighborhood of the first conjugate point $q$, there exists a point $z$ such that there are at least two distinct geodesics that connects $p$ and $z$.

For $c(s,t)$ to be a $C^1$ variation of $\gamma$, its corresponding initial speed vectors have to be continuous in $s$ for $s \in (-a,a)$. This continuity is a sufficient condition to pass differentiation (with respect to $s$) under the integral sign (with respect to $t$) when proving the first variation formula, and of course, a weaker sufficient condition is to assume that the supremum norm of the partial derivative (here as covariant derivative along $\gamma$) in $s$ of $c(s,t)$ is upper bounded by a Lebesgue integrable function $Q(t)$ and then apply the dominate convergence theorem to pass differentiation under the integral sign in order to prove the first variation formula.

**Here is what I tried**:

- Take a geodesic $h(s)$ such that $h(0)=q$ and $h'(0)=\mathbf{w}$ for $s \in (-a,a)$ for some $a>0$;
- For each $s$, let $K_s$ be the set of initial velocity vectors (in $T_p M$) of all the minimizing geodesics that connect $p$ and $h(s)$. Note that $K_s$ is non-empty by Hopf-Rinow theorem, and that  $K_s$ is a compact subset of $T_p M$ for each $s \in (-a,a)$;
- Now the key issue of picking initial velocity vectors. Fix an $s$, let $\mathbf{v}_s$ be the element of $K_s$ that has the smallest angle with $\gamma'(0)=\mathbf{v}$. Set $\sigma_s(t)$ to be the minimizing geodesic connecting $p$ and $h(s)$ such that $\sigma'_s(0)=\mathbf{v}_s$.

**Missing part in my trial:**  The above construction only asserts that $\mathbf{v}_{s_{j}} \to \mathbf{v}$ along each sequence $s_j \to 0$ (because $\gamma$ is the unique, minimizing geodesic connecting $p$ and $q$), and it does not imply that $\mathbf{v}_s$ is continuous in $s$ for $s \in (-a,a)$. Here continuity is defined with respect to the Riemannian metric on $T_p M$ and the canonical norm (i.e., absolute value of difference) on $(-a,a)$.

Any suggestions or points would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your condition 2 makes no sense, it is probably a typo.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Moishe. But if you look into the proof outline of Proportion 1.8 of the paper "Optimal transport and curvature" by Alessio Figalli and Cedric Villani, you will see that condition 2 is absolutely needed because we are looking into the differentiability of the squared distance function, for which each member of the variation has to be a minimizing geodesic.